# Passing Video File Input to p5js Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, upload, html5-video, p5.js

I am trying to use Bootstrap to create a prettier interface to upload a video file rather than the p5js "createFileInput()" function. I want the video in p5js so I can overlay animations onto it. For some reason my code is displaying the video twice as soon as I use the function "createVideo" and if I try and hide the DOM that is the second video outside of the canvas it disappears from the p5js canvas. Here is my code:

```
var view = {
    vid: "",   
    cHeight: 500, 
    cWidth: 700, 
    xVid: 0, 
    yVid: 0, 
};

function setup() {
    let cnv = createCanvas(view.cWidth, view.cHeight);
    cnv.id("p5jsCanvas"); 
}

function draw() {
    if (view.vid) {
        // We have an uploaded video so draw it
        //background(0);
        console.log(view.vid.id()); 
        image(view.vid, view.xVid, view.yVid);
    } else {
        background(0); 
    }
}

$("#videoFileUpload").on("change", function() {
    var fileName = $(this).val().split("\\").pop();
    $(this).siblings(".custom-file-label").addClass("selected").html(fileName);
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
        console.log(this.files[0]);
        var fileLocation = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]); 
        console.log(fileLocation);
        view.vid = createVideo([fileLocation], resizeVid);
        view.vid.id("poseVid");
    }

});


function resizeVid(){
  // If the height is greater than the width use the height to scale and AUTO for the width
  if (view.vid.height > view.vid.width){
    console.log("height > width");
    view.vid.size(AUTO, cHeight);
  } else { // Else if the width is greater than or equal to the height use the width to scale and AUTO for the height
    view.vid.size(view.cWidth, AUTO);
  } 

  // Reset location of the  video
  let currW = $("#poseVid").attr('width');
  let currH = $("#poseVid").attr('height'); 
  view.xVid = (view.cWidth - currW)/2; 
  view.yVid = (view.cHeight - currH)/2; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I needed to use hide() on the video element and then provide a way to "play" the element in p5js and then it worked. I also added removing the id if it existed already so that I could upload a different video after one was already uploaded.

```
var view = {
    vid: "",   
    cHeight: 500, 
    cWidth: 700, 
    xVid: 0, 
    yVid: 0, 
};

function setup() {
    let cnv = createCanvas(view.cWidth, view.cHeight);
    cnv.id("p5jsCanvas"); 
}

function draw() {
    if (view.vid) {
        // We have an uploaded video so draw it
        //background(0);
        console.log(view.vid.id()); 
        image(view.vid, view.xVid, view.yVid);
    } else {
        background(0); 
    }
}

$("#videoFileUpload").on("change", function() {
    var fileName = $(this).val().split("\\").pop();
    $(this).siblings(".custom-file-label").addClass("selected").html(fileName);
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
        console.log(this.files[0]);
        var fileLocation = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]); 
        console.log(fileLocation);
        $("#poseVid").remove(); // ADDED
        view.vid = createVideo([fileLocation], resizeVid);
        // view.vid.id("poseVid"); // MOVED TO resizeVid function
    }

});
// ADDED FUNCTION JUST TO TEST THE PLAYBACK
function mousePressed() {
     view.vid.loop(); // set the video to loop and start playing
}

function resizeVid(){
  // If the height is greater than the width use the height to scale and AUTO for the width

  view.vid.id("poseVid"); //MOVED INTO THIS FUNCTION
  $("#poseVid").hide(); //ADDED

  if (view.vid.height > view.vid.width){
    console.log("height > width");
    view.vid.size(AUTO, cHeight);
  } else { // Else if the width is greater than or equal to the height use the width to scale and AUTO for the height
    view.vid.size(view.cWidth, AUTO);
  } 

  // Reset location of the  video
  let currW = $("#poseVid").attr('width');
  let currH = $("#poseVid").attr('height'); 
  view.xVid = (view.cWidth - currW)/2; 
  view.yVid = (view.cHeight - currH)/2; 

}
```